# Ruby test unit: uninitialized constant Test::Unit::UnitCase

Tags: ruby, testunit

I am trying to run this test, but I am running int a problem. Every time that I attempt to run the test, I am getting the following error:

uninitialized constant Test::Unit::UnitCase

I am running it on Windows 7, ruby 186.
Path points to C:\ruby186\bin
Ruby Bin C:\ruby186\bin

This is not a rails app. This is just ruby.

This is the code:

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'test/unit'
require 'shoulda'
require './AngryBadger'

class AngryBadger < Test::Unit::UnitCase

  def setup
    test_uri = ""
    @ab = AngryBadger.new()
  end

  should "have no fear" do
   assert(true)
  end
end
```

I suspect that this can be fixed through configuration, but I don't know what I could do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be subclassing from `Test::Unit::TestCase` instead:

```
class AngryBadger < Test::Unit::TestCase
```

Comment: A note: I changed the name of the class since I noticed that I forgot to change it when I first posted the code.